# Rails with doorkeeper. How to make a secondary devise authentication controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, devise

I have a Rails app that authenticate users using Devise. This app is also an OAuth provider using Doorkeeper. Currently, when a user authenticate itself to allow a third party app to access the API, the user is redirected to the normal "catch all" page for authentication. I would like to make a special login view/controller for users authenticating for OAuth. I could make a view that post info to the devise sign_in action, but then any error would redirect to the default devise actions and views.

Is there any way to create a secondary authentication controller for Devise?

EDIT : I made a login view and it redirect on the main login page on login failure.

The alternate login view does not work for OAuth, intead of redirecting to the consumer app it redirect to root.